# JavaScript variables - HTML5 canvas issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, canvas

In the following code, I change an HTML5 canvas font by passing a string. Then in the second case, I use an array and variables. The first case works. The second case does not change fonts.  Problem is probably in the way I construct the variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas> 

<script>
// array of fonts
var fontArray = new Array();    
fontArray.push("Antiqua");            
fontArray.push("Arial");  
fontArray.push("Comic Sans");    

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// This works
context.font  = "25pt Arial";   
context.fillText('This works ', 30, 30);            
context.font  = "25pt Monospace";   
context.fillText('This works ', 30, 80);            


// This works but shows no varaition of font
for(x=0;x<3;x++){
    var fontText = "\'" + "20pt " + fontArray[x] + "\'" ;           
    context.font  = fontText;
    console.log(fontText);   // print to console
    context.fillText('This works but shows no variation of font', 120, 140+(x*50));             
}
</script>
```

Comment: There's no need for the escaped single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you change:

`var fontText = "\'" + "20pt " + fontArray[x] + "\'" ;`

to

`var fontText = "20pt " + fontArray[x];`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't wrap the font string in single quotes. Remote that and it should work.

```
var fontText = "20pt " + fontArray[x];
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QhV5U/).

Another reason is that the fonts probably are not available on the client.